# Unable to create docker machine stuck at "Waiting for an IP..."

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtualbox, docker-machine

I am trying to create docker machine with the following command but I am stuck at `Waiting for an IP...` from past an hour how long does it takes to create a docker machine

```
$ sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check manager1
```

[image: 20210304-121542.jpg]

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Google Cloud Platform)
Docker Version: 20.10.2
Docker Machine Version: 0.16.0
```

Comment: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/457#issuecomment-228413123